# 'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp'

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-msal, adal, microsoft-identity-web

I'm attempting to add support for Graph into a .Net 6 application.  I've previously used Graph in a .Net 5 application but I'm having some trouble understanding how to wire things up using the .Net 6 "simplified" startup.

I've included both:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
```

in the header of Program.cs but I'm getting an error with **AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp** in the following:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error   CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm fairly sure that I'm overlooking something pretty simple, but I cannot find it.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response.

As it turns out, I found that the problem was with an incorrect package being installed.  I had included Decos.Microsoft.Indentity.Web in the packages for the solution.  I suspect that there were some collisions occurring here.  Once I removed the package the error no longer manifests itself.

Answer (score 1):

> **"Error   CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' accepting a first  argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you  missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

**To resolve the above error, please try the below suggestions if helpful:**

- When you are including `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` packages, these libraries are used to simplify the process of signing-in a user and acquiring tokens for Microsoft Graph.
- Try modifying your ***configured services method*** by removing the prefix **`builder`** like below:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

- To sign-in a user for your application with Microsoft identity platform endpoint `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()` is used.
- `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()` and `AddMicrosoftGraph` adds support to call Microsoft Graph.
- **Otherwise**, If you want to use **`builder`**, make sure to add the package using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and define the **`builder`** as below:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/README.md at master · Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md#run-the-sample).

[Configure ASP.NET Core Identity | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0).